# Torbutton broke Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, tor

I'm using Firefox Aurora on Ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to use Torbutton for certain websites, however the add-on has been causing problems, such as constantly spitting out errors about it not being able to get a mouse event or something. I uninstalled it, however since then I have some problems.

Firstly, download history no longer works (even though I re-enabled it in about:config).

Secondly, speed dial thumbnails no longer generate.

Finally, I think Sync is now broken (although I can't be sure, because I haven't synced in ages).

How do I fix it?

Thanks,
Filip

Comment: Did you try creating a fresh profile and seeing whether the problems still occur in the new one?

Comment: Thanks, and the problem does not in fact carry over. I'll see what else I can do before resetting everything.

Comment: @FilipLamparski: You could try copying files over from the old profile to the new one - until you find the one causing the issue (likely to be `prefs.js` so you might want to start with this one).

Answer (score 1):

Recent Firefox versions have a [Reset Firefox feature](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) that is very useful in situations where something has been misconfigured but you don't know what. Simply type `about:support` into the location bar and click the "Reset Firefox" button on the right. You will have to reinstall your extensions but all the usual browsing data should be kept.